# Spring Web MVC 4+ with Java 8: best way to make chained DeferredResult callbacks in the service layer?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, asynchronous

UPDATE: I upgraded the code to Java 8 without too much of a hassle. So I would like answers tied to Spring 4/Java 8.

I am working on a task to fix performance issues (Tomcat max thread count  of 200 reached at a request rate of just 400/s, request latencies building up periodically, etc) in a Tomcat/Spring 4.2.4/Java 8 web mvc application.

It is a typical web application which looks up Mysql via Hibernate for small but frequent things like user info per request, then does actual data POST/GET to another web service via RestTemplate.

The code is in Java 7 style as I just migrated to Java 8, but no new code has been written in that style yet. (I am also back using Spring after ages, so not sure what would be best).

As expected in a normal such application, the Service layer calls other services for info, and then also passes that along to a call to the DAO. So I have some dependent callbacks here.

**Setup**

- @EnableAsync is set
- The flow of our Http requests goes from Controller -> Service -> DAO -> REST or Hibernate

**Sample flow**

1. Say Controller receives POST request R and expects a DeferredResult
2. Controller calls entityXService.save()
3. EntityXService calls userService.findUser(id)
4. UserService calls UserDAO.findUser(id) which in turn talks to Hibernate
5. UserService returns a Spring ListenableFuture to the caller
6. EntityXService awaits the user info (using callback) in and calls EntityXDAO.save(user, R)
7. EntityXDAO calls AsyncRestTemplate.postForEntity(user, R)
8. EntityXDAO receives DeferredResult> which is our data abstraction for the response.
9. EntityXDAO processes the response and converts to EntityXDTO
10. Eventually somehow the DeferredResult is sent back through the same chain as a response.

I am getting lost at how in step 3, EntityXService asynchronously calls UserService.findUser(id) with an onSuccess callback to EntityXDAO.save(user, R). However, EntityXDAO.save(user, R) also now returns a DeferredResult from the AsyncRestTemplate.

**Questions:**

1. Is using DeferredResult a good way to get concurrency going in this application?
2. Is using Guava's ListenableFuture or Java 8 CompletableFuture going to help make it better in anyway, rather than using DeferredResult?
3. My BIGGEST question and confusion is how to arrange the DeferredResult from one service lookup to be used by another, and then finally set a DeferredResult of a completely different return type for the final response?
4. Is there an example of how to chain such callbacks and what is the recommended way to build such a flow? If this sounds completely wrong, is Java 7 going to be the right choice for this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you ever solve this? I'm looking at a similar situation.